# TransferUtility.download in android is stuck in WAITING state

Tags: android, amazon-s3

I'm using TransferUtility.download to get a file from a bucket but the transfer state is stuck in WAITING forever.

While searching for answers the most common answer I found for this is to check I have the transfer service enabled. I have ensured I do without misspelling it:

```
<service android:name="com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferService"
         android:enabled="true" />
```

Also I can upload a file all fine. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to figure out the reason but once I started firing only one request at a time it seems to have fixed itself.